# Why is CDF the only way to randomly select from samples?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am confused with the concept of cumulative distribution function (CDF).
I see it helps in algorithms related to sampling of data. So for instance if we have a list of values, and we randomly want to pick up some elements with probability dependent on their value, CDF helps us with that in an efficient manner.
What I am confused is why for this particular case an algorithm such as the following is not correct but we have to use CDF.
Algorithm:

1. Sum all elements of the array/stream of elements $w_n$ we want to sample and get the total sum.
2. Keep a mapping of individual elements with their positions in the array/stream. This is required for duplicate entries
3. Pick a random number in the range of $[0, total Sum)$
4. Scan linearly the array and check for each element if the random number selected is less than or equal to $\frac{w_i}{total Sum}*100$. If yes then
   4.a if there is only 1 occurence of the element $w_i$ in the list return $i$
   4.b if there are $k$ occurences of the element $w_i$ in the list select a random number in the range of $[0, k)$ and return the corresponding index in the original array $w$

It seems to me that this algorithm takes into account each element's "weight" in the array, it takes into account duplicates and is random.

But I have verified via testing that it is wrong.
What is the error in reasoning that makes it impossible to use this and CDF is the only correct approach?

**Update:**
To be clear the expectation is that for e.g. the input array $[5,15,20,30,30]$ then index $0$ is picked $5\%$ of the time, index $1$ is picked $15\%$ of the time,$2$ is picked $20\%$ of the time, $3$ is picked $30\%$ of the time and $4$ is picked $30\%$ of the time. CDF solves this, I am trying to understand why the algorithm I suggested does not if it essentially takes the percentages into account in the linear scan

Comment: Can you add an example with 10 numbers to show the steps. since I am still not clear on what total_sum is in this case.

Comment: @Chinny84: If the array is $w = [2,3,4,4,4,1]$ total sum is $ 2 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 = 18$

Comment: Using the inverse of the CDF is not the only way of sampling from a distribution.  For example, rejection sampling can use the pdf without needing to integrate or invert, and can be faster.  Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975300/speed-of-random-sampling-from-distribution-in-r) - the square of the semicircle distribution

Comment: $w_i = [5,15,20,30, 30]$ Leads to 
$$
\text{total_sum} = 100\\
\text{check_array} = \left[5,15,20,30, 30\right]
$$
now pick a number that is between $[30, 100)$ what do you want to happen? (this is just clearing up your algo for me)

Comment: @Henry: I wasnt aware of CDF and encountered it when looking into a coding exercise, and trying to understand the concept

Comment: @Chinny84: The algorithm would pick a random number between $[0, 100)$ first. Then would return the index of $check\_array$ of any element  $(w_i / 100)*100$ that is greater than random number we have chosen. In the case of $30$ it would also pick randomly between $[3,4]$ which are the indexes of $30$. This selection should be random to be considered correct

Comment: @Chinny84: Basically the expectation is that for your input array $[5,15,20,30,30]$ then index $0$ is picked $5%$ of the time, index $1$ is picked $15%$ of the time,$2$ is picked $20%$ of the time, $3$ is picked $30%$ of the time and $4$ is picked $30%$ of the time. CDF solved this, I am trying to understand why the algorithm I suggested does not. It essentially takes the percentages into account in the linear scan

Comment: You're comparing/contrasting the above algorithm with some other unexplained method that uses a CDF. It's hard to say much here without knowing a lot more about what that other method is. Can you give a link to the mentioned coding exercise?

Comment: @r.e.s.: yes, https://leetcode.com/problems/random-pick-with-weight/

Comment: @Chinny84: Did my explanations help? I don't really know the CDF topic, so I might need help phrasing everything in a way that is clearest

Comment: @r.e.s.: The expectation is to pick items from an array randomly with the expectation that the frequency of an item being picked up being dependent on its ratio of its value over the total sum. E.g.  For $[5,15,20,30,30]$ then index 0 is picked $5\%$ of the time, index $1$ is picked $15\%$ of the time , index $3$ is selected $30\%$ of the time etc. The approach I am suggesting takes into account the ratio since it does $(w_i / sum)*100$ to pick a random element

Answer (score 3):

The cited link asks for a method to generate a random integer $I\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ according to the distribution specified by a list of positive integer weights $w_0,\dots,w_{n-1}$, such that $P(I=j)=w_j/\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}w_i$.

The so-called "CDF method" is as follows:

> Return the least $i$ such that $CDF(i)\ge U$, where $U\sim\text{Uniform$(0,1)$}$ and $CDF(i) = \sum_{j=0}^iP(I=j)= {\sum_{j=0}^{i}w_j\over\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j}.$

NB: $U\sim\text{Uniform$(0,1)$}$ means that $U$ is a random variable with a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$. In a computer implementation, it would be realized by a pseudorandom real in that interval, e.g. `U=random()` in Python.)

This works, because $U$ must fall between two consecutive CDF values, and the rule just picks out the argument $j$ of the larger value:
$$\begin{align}P(\text{return $j$})&=P\bigg(\big(\text{least $i$ such that $CDF(i)\ge U$}\big)=j\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=P\bigg(CDF(j-1)\lt U\le CDF(j)\bigg)\\[2ex]
&=CDF(j) - CDF(j-1)\quad\text{because $U$ is Uniformly distributed}\\[2ex]
&={w_j\over\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}w_i}\quad \text{as required.}
\end{align}$$

Now, the algorithm you suggest has the following rule (assuming for now that the $w_i$ are distinct):

> Return the least $i$ such that $R\le 100{w_i\over\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j}$ where $R\sim\text{Uniform$(0,\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j)$}$

But $R/\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j\sim\text{Uniform$(0,1)$}$, so this is the same as

> Return the least $i$ such that $100{w_i\over(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j)^2}\ge U,$ where $U\sim\text{Uniform$(0,1)$}$.

Thus, contrasting/comparing this rule to that of the CDF method, we can see that  your method (in the case of distinct $w_i$) has just replaced $CDF(i)={\sum_{j=0}^{i}w_j\over\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j}$ by the *ad hoc* function $100{w_i\over(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j)^2}.$ Of course this means there is no possibility for this method to work as required. Other problems are also apparent; for example, your method is not scale invariant (as the CDF method is): multiplying all the weights by the same positive number must not change the result.

---

Your title suggests that the CDF method is the only way to sample a discrete distribution, but see the following for examples and links to many other ways: [How to generate numbers based on an arbitrary discrete distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26858/how-to-generate-numbers-based-on-an-arbitrary-discrete-distribution).

Comment: I didn't understand this part: `But /∑−1=0∼Uniform(0,1), so this is the same as....` also how did we get the square in the denominator?

Comment: @Jim (1) If $R\sim\text{Uniform$(0,b)$}$, then $R/b\sim\text{Uniform$(0,1)$}$. One way to prove this is to show that if $R$ has PDF $p_R(r)=(1/b)(0<r<b)$, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) $U=R/b$ has PDF $p_U(y)=p_R(yb)(b)=(1/b)(0<yb<b)(b)=1(0<y<1).$ (2) Now, your algorithm uses the inequality $R\le 100{w_i\over\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j}$, which is the same as $U={R\over\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j}\le 100{w_i\over(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j)^2}.$

Comment: I think your answer has very important details, I don't know enough about statistics to grasp it fully. E.g. `Return the least  such that ()≥` what do we mean by `U` here? Also I assume the `∼` means equivalent? `can be shown that if  is the CDF of ` where did that $F$ come from? Does it mean the function that implements the return of the index? Probably it is too much to ask, but depending on whether it is possible and you have some time, would it be possible to add some extra info more directed to the layman and an intuitive explanation?

Comment: @Jim Hopefully it's clearer now. It takes a bit of thought to see what's going on in the CDF method.

Comment: 1) `because  must fall between two consecutive CDF value` that is still not obvious to me.

Comment: 2) `Return the least  such that ≤100...`. I was adding the multiplication with $100$ since without it, it was <= 1. Now if I convert the $R$ to be random between $[0, 1)$ as the $U$ you describe, we end up with:
$R \ge \frac{w_i}{\sum}$. Why is that wrong?

Comment: @Jim (1) The CDF of a discrete r.v. is a step function with a jump at each possible value of the r.v., the amt. of jump being the prob. of that value. E.g. look at [this picture](http://sigmawiki.com/support/index.php?title=Methods_of_Generating_Random_Variates).  $U$ is a random number in $(0,1)$ so it falls in exactly one interval $0\le F(x_{i-1})\lt U\le F(x_i)<= 1$, as s.b. clear from the picture. The method generates $P(X=x_i)$ because the prob. of $U$ falling in a given interval equals the interval width (i.e. the amt. of jump): $P(F(x_{i-1})\lt U\le F(x_i))=F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})=P(X=x_i).$

Comment: @Jim (2) Your rule uses the criterion $R\le 100\,w_i/\text{totalSum}$, where $R$ is uniform on the interval $(0, \text{totalSum}).$ I think the easiest way to see that this *cannot* be correct is just to look at what happens if we change every $w_i$ to $2w_i$. This should lead to no change whatsoever in the algorithm output, but it does: the RHS of the criterion does *not* change (because doubling each $w_i$ doubles both the numerator & denominator), but the LHS *does* change, as $R$ now takes values in an interval twice as wide (because $\text{totalSum}$ has doubled).